# SKLabelNode blurry when zoomed in with SKCameraNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having a problem that I just can't solve. I've been looking for hours now to fix this, I can't find anything.

I have `SKScene` that got a `SKShapeNode` and `SKLabelNode`. I'm also using a `SKCameraNode` that's zooming into the scene (using a scale action). When I do this, it looks like this:

[image]

The circle is sharp (though it's not pretty) but the main problem is the label that clearly blurry.

Is there a way to keep the label sharp when zooming in? If not, what a better way to zoom into a scene without losing quality?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

`SKLabelNode` unfortunately gets blurry when the camera zooms in.

If the `SKLabelNode` were a child on the `SKCameraNode` the problem would not occur, but this is only helpful on a scoreboard or HUD that the camera movement should not impact.

A *dirty* solution for a higher-quality SKLabelNode is to render it with a large font size, convert it to an `SKSpriteNode` and then scale it down again:

```
let scaleFactor = 5.0
let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Test")
label.fontSize = 12.0 * scaleFactor

let spriteText = SKSpriteNode(texture: view.texture(from: label))
spriteText.xScale = 1 / scaleFactor
spriteText.yScale = 1 / scaleFactor
addChild(spriteText)
```

You can try various values for the `scaleFactor` and see if the result is to your liking.

(Note that if you don't have access to your view you can use `SKView().texture(from: label)` in line 5).

Comment: Thank you for this! I used your idea and scaled up the font size, then scaled down the label node itself by the inverse factor, and it looks OK.

Further testing is required to see how the scaling may affect other behaviors such as physics simulations.

What is the benefit of converting the label node into a sprite node? I tried both solutions and the visual rendering seems equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

The `SKCameraNode` has its own scale function, so you wouldn't need to use a scale action.

```
guard let camera = self.childNode(withName: "gameCamera") as? SKCameraNode else {
    fatalError("Camera node not loaded")
}

camera.setScale(1.75)
```

Comment: I want to animate the scale. Also, don't the scale action just change and animate the scale of the cameraNode? Or is my understanding of this wrong?

Comment: Can I do this? `MyGameScene(size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width * 4, height: bounds.size.height * 4))` I make the scene way bigger than the `SKView` that holds it. This way the label is sharp, even when zoomed in. Do you think this is a viable solution?

Comment: @Quantm, this is why you should always show code,  running `SKAction.scaleTo` on camera will do the same thing as this code, but over a duration

Comment: @Quantm, no you do not want to do that

Comment: 1) I know, that's what I wrote in the question. I'm zooming in (doesn't matter if it's animated or not), but the label gets blurry. 
2) Why not? I think this increases the amount of pixels/points in the scene. It's working perfectly, what is negative about this approach (maybe I don't see it)

Comment: Did you try `MyGameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))` and `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill`?

Comment: You quadruple your memory footprint

Comment: Hm, I just checked the size, if I use 4 time the bounds (which is only part of the screen), I get a size of (w:1280,h:1920) on iPhone X. So that's not too bad, is it? To give more context (which was not necessary for the question before you mentioned the size aspect): I'm not making a whole game with this scene. I just wanna use it to illustrate some data in a graphical, animated way. My question: Is it a problem to *not* hard-code the size? I always see tutorials using hard-coded sizes. But I don't use any assets here. I also display the content in a square (defined by the width of the size).

Comment: I never recommend hard coding size,  Stick to a static size using the SKS file.  This helps reduce problems when coding tends to contribute to creating bugs,  if you want to discuss more, open a chat because we are now getting beyond the scope of the question at hand